# Rails: Connecting Model to another Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, rails-activerecord

I just created new columns in my database for my micropost table and these columns were `vote_count` `comment_count` and I want to connect it to the Vote models vote_up count and the  Comment models comment count. Since I just added these columns although there were votes and comments, how do I connect these other models to the micropost model to fill in the new columns. Any suggestions are much appreciated!

**Micropost Model**

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content, :view_count
  acts_as_voteable
  belongs_to :school
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
  has_many :views
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you're trying to do is use a `counter_cache`, which rails supports, but you've got the names of the columns wrong.

You want to add a `comments_count` and a `votes_count` column to your database instead of the ones that you have.

Then you can hook it up to your models as follows:

```
class Micropost< ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content, :view_count
  acts_as_voteable
  belongs_to :school
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, :counter_cache => true
  has_many :views
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end
```

The votes half of it is a bit more tricky since you're using some extra code with your `acts_as_votable` module, but counter caches are the way that you want to go if I understand you correctly.

Here is more info on them: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: I have a comments_count column in the mircopost table and does this column just automatically count the number of comments that micropost have? Also for the votes, since I am using acts_as_voteable I'm assuming there is more to it then just automatically counting?

Comment: Well for comments, it will automatically increment/decrement comments_count for you.  You can always just called `comments_count` to get the current number of comment for your micropost.

For acts_as_votable, look here: https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable under 'Caching', you just need to add some columns to the database as they specify and it will do as you want it to do.

Comment: mmm I already have some comments before I added this column, is there a way to update this and save it into this column? Also for the votes process would you know how to go about doing this?

Comment: Just initialize the <code>comments_count</code> to however many comments you already have and it should take over form there.

Comment: Understood, would you know about how to go about the votes issue?

Comment: Like I said, just look under 'Caching' on the github page for it, which is right here, its the exact step by step instructions you need. https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable

Comment: Would you have any idea why I am getting this error? `Unknown key: counter_cache`

Comment: Yeah, that's my mistake, you can only use <code>counter_cache</code> on a <code>belongs_to</code> association.  I'll update my answer in a second.